# drawing dotted lines from UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext

I have a UIViewController which has a UIView in it and I want to draw a straight dotted line on it. What is the easiest and performant way to do this? How do I do this? It will just be a straight horizontal dotted line of width 150 with gray color. I've looked around and it seems that using
CGContextSetLineDash is the solution and here's what I have so far:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 100);
  CGFloat dashes[] = {1,1};
  CGContextSetLineDash(context, 2.0, dashes, 2);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: In order to get useful answers, you need to show what you've done and where you're stuck. No one will write a whole program for you, but we're happy to help with specific steps and nudges in the right direction.

Comment: sorry, I just added my code and where I am at.. mind not down voting my question?

Comment: What happens when you use this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGContextStrokePath` draws the *current* path, however, you never add any path to your context, so nothing is drawn.

Add the following two lines before your `CGContextStrokePath` call and you should see something:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height * 0.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height * 0.5);
```

If you haven't already set your stroke color, you should also add something like this (50% gray):

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
```

I'm not sure if the result is really what you want, a 100 point dotted line with a pattern of {1, 1} will look more like an rectangle with a pinstripe pattern than like a dotted line. If you want your dots to be circles, you will have to draw those manually in some sort of loop.

Comment: hmm..so how do I get a dotted lines? what will the pattern should be?

Comment: What do you want it to look like, could you perhaps show a picture?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);


CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGFloat lengths[] = {0, 8};
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0f, lengths, 2);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10,  10);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 10);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```